# R - Error message in surveyglm after using droplevels

Tags: r, survey

I am trying to include an independent variable in my logistic regression model using the function `surveyglm`.

It keeps giving me the error code

> "Error in `contrasts`<-(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
>     contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels".

The code is:

```
finaldes<-svydesign(id=~CPSUM, strata=~CSTRATM, weights=~PATWT, nest=TRUE,data=newpts)

(log<-svyglm(formula=offlabel ~ AGER + siteofcare + MSA, design=finaldes))

summary(log)
```

And the variable that is giving me trouble is siteofcare. When I check the number of levels, I get 2 as an output so I don't understand why this isn't working.

```
> levels(newpts$siteofcare)
[1] "Outpt" "Hosp" 
> nlevels(newpts$siteofcare)
[1] 2
```

Comment: `x = factor(1, levels=0:1)` had two levels but will throw an error. Hm where have you used droplevels?

Comment: I used it when creating the variable and adding it to my dataset. newpts$siteofcare<-droplevels(siteofcare), where siteofcare is the original with extra levels.

Comment: okay, does you data have any missing rows. If so, perhaps the rows that are removed for this reason in the modelling, only leave one level of that variable. What does `table(finaldes$variables$siteofcare)` give

Comment: If you `dput` your dataset we may be able to reproduce problem.

Answer (score 0):

coerce all four of the columns used in your svyglm call to factor types in the data.frame newpts before the svydesign statement